# Anomaly detection using exponential weighted moving average?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, predictive-models, anomaly-detection, exponential-smoothing

I would like to detect anomaly using exponential weighted moving average.

I don't have series of data points. All I have is EMA<sub>(t-1)</sub> and the data point of the current time(t) DP<sub>(t)</sub>.

From these data, I can calculate the new EMA<sub>(t)</sub>. The EWMA constant will be 0.85 (assuming).

Now I have two EMAs={EMA<sub>(t-1)</sub> ,EMA<sub>(t)</sub>} and DP<sub>(t)</sub>.

Is it possible to determine whether DP<sub>t</sub> is anomaly or not? using any logic?

---

For Example:

```
Time(t) DataPoint(t)    EMA(t-1)    EMA(t)  
1       120               0          102    
.        .                .           . 
.        .                .           . 
.        .                .           . 
.        .                .           . 
.        .                .           .     
10      300              150        277.5
```

I don't want to take series of data points into calculation.

At any time instance say 10, I want to know whether the data point 300 (in this case) is an anomaly or not. I also have the EMA<sub>(9)=150</sub> and EMA(10)=277.5 for calculation (if needed)

Is there any logic to calculate this?

---

Update:

I thought of the below logic but not sure whether it would work for sure

```
ABS(DP-EMA(new))> 3 *SD {EMA(old),EMA(new)}
```

(or)

```
ABS(DP-EMA(new))> 3 *EMWSD {EMA(old),EMA(new)}
```

DP - Data Point
EMA - Exponential Weighted Moving Average
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ctwu.png

Comment: what do you mean by anomaly? An outlier?

Comment: @CarrKnight yes!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you keep a moving average and moving variance? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14638138/975904) for useful way to code them.
When you do, you can tag as anomaly anything that is, say, 3 standard deviations away from the moving average.

Notice that it's hard to tell what is an anomaly without making an assumption of what is normal i.e. what is the data generating process.

Comment: I have the Exponential Moving Averages (Old & New). Can't we not use these along with the DP to calculate anomaly.. 
I  thought of a logic to calculate the anomaly but I m not sure whether it is the right one?
Anomaly is true if
(DP-EMA(new))>3*StandardDeviation{EMA(old),EMA(new)}. It could be a regular SD or EMSD.

Comment: I am not really sure where you get that formula. What is the standard deviation of two elements (very strongly related) supposed to tell you? Also $\text{DP}-\text{EMA}(\text{new})$ is what exactly? $\text{DP}-(1-\alpha)\text{EMA}(\text{old})-\alpha\text{DP} $ or $(1-\alpha) (\text{DP} - \text{EMA}(\text{old}) )$. How can this be a sign of anomaly if it depends not so much on the data but on the weight of exponential?

Comment: I thought of this logic with the following criteria in mind.
1. DP−EMA(new) = Will give you the deviation of the DP from the Average (EMA(new)).
2. EMSD{(EMAnew) & (EMAold))} would give us the value of the deviation of the both the EMA.

I may be wrong but thought of this approach

Comment: @CarrKnight If the series was 1,9,1,9,1,9,1,9,1,9,5,9,1,9,1,9,1,9 would your approach detect the anomaly or would the "5" be acceptable ?.

Comment: 5 would be acceptable. My "method" is for numerical outliers (too big/too small) not for logical ones. Maybe some well defined classifier would work but it is far more complicated